Simple WIXL config to copy over and execute exe
I am trying to put together a simple wixl config. I have a 150mb exe, and I need to generate an MSI for easier deployment. When run, the MSI just needs to copy embedded exe over to the system and execute it, that's it.
Here is what I have for the config: https://gist.github.com/defensivedepth/d29b8c2a4c846cc5520446f6650f2d2d
When I test the MSI, I end up with:
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:22:468]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=custom_installer.exe,SourceCabKey=EXEFile,DestName=custom_installer.exe,Attributes=512,FileSize=157495808,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=-157916039,HashPart2=1191719925,HashPart3=2041815197,HashPart4=-361054475,,)
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:22:468]: File: C:\Users\ONIONU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\TempInstall\custom_installer.exe;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:22:468]: Source for file 'EXEFile' is compressed
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:22:765]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:015]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:249]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:484]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:718]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:953]: Note: 1: 1335 2: app.cab 
MSI (s) (A4:C0) [14:29:23:953]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 

Using 7zip, I can extract the exe from the MSI and manually execute, so I know that it is not corrupted.
Full installer log: https://gist.github.com/defensivedepth/7c7e62b92417d4210fc7196c110293e7
Any ideas?

The design of WIXL is that it's a WiX like compiler that only understands a subset of the WiX schema and doesn't perform MSI validation post build.
I while I didn't investigate the orginal error I did spend two hours with Josh to reproduce his MSI from scratch and then work backwards until WIXL was happy. The result can be found at:
https://github.com/defensivedepth/msi-testing/blob/dev/wixl/Product.wxs

Something appears wrong with the MSI you've built. The MSI error code 1335 means:

msi 1335
The cabinet file '[2]' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

Also, the "full log file" in the gist is incomplete. 7-zip is not the same as the Windows Installer and may be more forgiving about the corruption. Or there may be additional information in the log file that would be written when the Windows Installer is allowed to complete.
